# Python ib-insync error - "There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-6(--)'"

Tags: python, python-multithreading, ib-insync

I created a thread in the main code. Inside the thread I call a procedure outside the thread. The called procedure runs fine except a line that's supposed to run an ib order, which throws the error "There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-6(--)'"

I've tried ensuring the ib global variable is writable in the called procedure but it doesn't help. See below code.

```
#Global variables
ib = ""

class StartRunning():

   def __init__(self):  
    print("Starting up...")

   def myMain()
     global ib
 
     ib = IB()                                  
     ib.connect("127.0.0.1", port, clientId) 

   def SaleProcess():       
    
      try:      
      ...................
      StartRunning.ProcessSS(x)                                                                             
      
      except Exception as ex:
       print("SaleProcess: ", ex)
       pass    

 
   def ProcessSS(x): 

     try:
                         
         StartRunning.RunOrder()                 
                  
     except Exception as ex:
       print("Error in ProcessSS: ", ex)
       return False 

   def RunOrder():
      
     global ib
     
     try:

        theOrder = Order()
        theOrder.orderId = ib.client.getReqId()
        theOrder.action = theAction
        thePrice = StartRunning.GetPriceVolGap(theSymbol) 
        theOrder.auxPrice = getauxPrice()      #trailing amount 
        theOrder.orderType = "TRAIL"                              
        theOrder.totalQuantity = theQuantity
        theOrder.transmit = True 
        theOrder.eTradeOnly = None
        theOrder.firmQuoteOnly = None 
        theOrder.nbboPriceCap = None  
        contract = Stock(theSymbol, 'SMART', 'USD')     
        ib.placeOrder(contract, theOrder) 

        return True        
        
     except Exception as ex:
       print("Error in RunOrder: ", ex)
       return False     


#MAIN STRUCTURE
def main():
  try:            
   
   while True:    
            thread1 = Thread(target=StartRunning.SaleProcess)
            thread1.start()
            StartRunning.MyMain()

  except Exception as ex:
       print("Error in main: ", ex)
       pass
   
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()     `
```

Comment: The code you provided gives no insight into how you are controlling the threads, how you are using asyncio, or which line of code the error comes from.  A full traceback is almost always a good idea, as is including in your code the line that triggered the exception.  What you show here is pretty much meaningless.  There are a lot of people here who are willing to help, but the only thing they know about your problem is what you post.